# How to fix: the program doesn't compile more than 76 elements in a vector

Tags: c++

I copy and paste information from an excel file yet the vector I created to store these information. The problem is that the program doesn't run if I pasted more than 76 elements that are copied from the excel file at once. Yet if I copied and pasted 50 elements and then 50 other ones again the program runs fine.

I tried to put in the information manually and it does work. I also tried to set the size of the vector to 100 for example. In this case if I pasted 100 items from excel at once the program just give me whitespaces. Yet if I posted 50 elements and then another 50 the program works fine.

These are relevant parts of the code.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include<math.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    unsigned long long int csize1; //size of list 1
    unsigned long long int csize2; //size of list 2
    long double ThetaX;// Declear ThetaX.
    long double ThetaZ;// Declear ThetaZ.
    unsigned long long int i;
    unsigned long long int j;

    cout<<"Enter the size of the first list --->  ";
    cin>>csize1;

    vector<long double> Date1(csize1); //Dates1 declear.
    vector<long double> Eng1(csize1); //  Eng of list 1 decleared.

    cout<<"Enter the Dates of the first list:  \n"; //Entring the first list date
    for ( i=0.0; i<Date1.size(); ++i) {
        cin>>Date1.at(i);

    }

    cout<<"Enter the Eng of the first list:   \n"; // Entrign the Eng for the first list.
    for(int i=0.0; i<Eng1.size(); ++i) {
        cin>>Eng1.at(i);

    }
```

There is no error message that appears when I run the program. put if I post more than 76 elements at once and I press enter the program just shows more whitespace to put more data.

Comment: What does "the excel file" contain? This smells like some Windows clipboard size limit rather than a C++ issue.

Comment: Either way, copy-pasting data from Excel by hand does not seem like a very user-friendly approach. Have you considered exporting your spreadsheet to CSV and processing that in C++? Alternatively, copy your data to a text file first and feed the text file to your program.

Comment: Side note; initializing an integer with a floating point value (`i = 0.0`) makes little sense.

Comment: I changed the integer initialization. The reason I try to copy and past is that I need the code to compute information I get from new excel files everyday. The files contains some integers listed in columns

Comment: So export to CSV and feed that to your program. It's quicker and less error-prone than copy-pasting columns by hand.